# Manipulating horizontal and vertical 'guidelines'

Tags: plotting, manipulate, locator

Is it possible to create an interactive plot that has drag-down / across horizontal & vertical guides a la Illustrator / InDesign?

I would like to generate something like this:

[image]

I would ideally like to drag multiple (unlimited?) horizontal and vertical guide lines, which would then stay in the positions that they are left in.

In addition (if it is not asking too much!) I would really like the guidelines to 'snap' to integers as well.

I have looked at various locator manipulations, with no success. Apologies for not including my *Mathematica* coding effort, but I don't really know where to start with this one :/

Comment: LocatorPane allows you to interactively add or remove Locators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cheap and cheerful:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
  {Round[xguide, 2],
   Plot[{PrimePi[x]},
    {x, 0, 200}, 
    PlotPoints -> 200,
    ImageSize -> 600,
    Epilog -> {Gray,
      Line[{{Round[xguide[[1]], 2], -1000}, {Round[xguide[[1]], 2], 
         1000}}],
      Line[{{-1000, Round[ xguide[[2]], 2]}, {1000, 
         Round[xguide[[2]], 2]}}]
      }]
   }],
 {{xguide, {20, 20}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

[image: rulers]

I'll leave you to explore the unlimited guides option... :)

Comment: @ Cormullion, great! thanks - gets me part way there ;)

Comment: Added 1/2 to `Round[xguide[[2]] + 0.5, 1]` & seems to 'snap' to plot points ok now :)

Comment: The rounding to 2 was only to make you notice `Round`. :) I had thought of decreasing the rounding strength as it approached the plotted line, but I got distracted...